# Java ComboBox change focus loop

Tags: java, loops, combobox, focus

We using java 1.7.0_21 and have some problems with ComboBoxes.
For example i create new Stage with two clear ComboBoxes.

```
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    ComboBox combo1 = new ComboBox();
    ComboBox combo2 = new ComboBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(combo1, combo2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();
```

When we lunch app, the focus stay on combo1.
After that we clicking by mouse away from our Stage.
And return into our stage by clicking on second ComboBox combo2 
(just right on combo2. do not reactivate stage)
As a result we have a loop of changing focuses between combo1 and combo2.

So what would be the proper way to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: could you explain a bit more like what you mean by "After that we clicking by mouse away from our Stage"? What is the `stage` in your code?

Comment: change focus from stage on desktop for example.

Comment: stage  - just a new scene, form, window..

Comment: The question is not actual. Thanks.